# Deployment Script with bash

Tags: bash, amazon-ec2, web-deployment

I had the below deployment script which I had used on an ec2 instance before and it worked perfectly, I terminated that instance and spun off a new instance but the script will not work on this new one, specifically the code that has to do with `npm` and `pm2`. It says those command do not exist.

I have installed nodejs, npm and pm2 on the instance, and when I ssh into the instance and I can run those commands manually.

```
tar  --exclude=./node_modules --exclude=./.git --exclude=./dist --exclude=./.env --exclude=./uploads -czvf deployment.tar.gz .
scp -r -i kp.pem deployment.tar.gz ubuntu@xx.xx.xxx.xxx:/home/ubuntu/api
ssh -i kp.pem ubuntu@xx.xx.xxx.xxx <<'ENDSSH'
    cd api
    tar -xvf deployment.tar.gz
    rm deployment.tar.gz
    rm ormconfig.json
    mv ormconfig.prod.json ormconfig.json
    mv .env.prod .env
    mkdir -p uploads
    npm install
    pm2 stop api
    pm2 delete api
    pm2 install typescript
    pm2 link xxxxxxxxx yyyyyyyyyy
    pm2 update
    pm2 start src/index.ts --source-map-support --name=api --trace
ENDSSH
rm deployment.tar.gz
```

Below is the error message I get.

```
-bash: line 8: npm: command not found
-bash: line 9: pm2: command not found
-bash: line 10: pm2: command not found
-bash: line 11: pm2: command not found
-bash: line 12: pm2: command not found
-bash: line 13: pm2: command not found
-bash: line 14: pm2: command not found
```

Comment: Your new instance may not have those tools installed. Try using the package manager to install them (e.g., sudo yum install npm).

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that neither of these files are on your path.  You can either add them to the path in the ssh command, or run `which npm` and `which pm2` while logged in normally and replace the commands in the ssh with the full paths.

Comment: I tried that, it says such directory does not exist